# Eclipse ide tasks tag problem

Tags: java, eclipse, task

I have been puzzled by the problem for several days: the task tags(TODO FIXME XXX and etc.) disappeared in tasks view in my working java project. What strange is this problem did not occur if a create a new project. Perhaps that's because I changed some configuration of my working project, but I can not figure out what it is,-_-!

Answer (score 0):

The task tags are under:

```
Window > Preferences
```

And then under:

```
Java > Compiler > Task Tags
```

Also you can check up in the top right corner there is a link for:

```
`Configure Project Specific Settings`
```

I think that's where you want to be

Answer (score 0):

Java Task Tags are only detected when a Build occurs (other than Clean), so leave automatic builds on if you want to get the most out of them.